# Debugging error visual studio when using c#

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3Bls.png)looking for help!

Recently created a new application to open excel in C# on visual studio, I created one fine and then had errors. I have created a few new ones since and I keep getting the same message every time I do a new project? I can't seem to figure out the issue? Any one got any suggestions at all?

Thank you!

Tried starting projects fresh, updated VS and also saw a forum on here for the error with no luck

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that the .exe file which should be generated and used is missing. Perhaps there are some build errors or there’s something wrong with the configuration.

Did you modify some project settings?
If you create a new project, without typing any code and then build and run the project, will the same error appear?
Please share us a minimal sample and some detailed steps to reproduce this issue.

Here are some possible causes and suggestions:

**Configurations**

1. Are you using a OneDrive folder or other similar folder(not local folder)? If so, please try to create and save the project into a local folder and test again. Sometimes, synchronization may not work correctly.
2. Right-click your project > Property > Build > make sure the Base output path is correctly set, for example `bin\`.
3. Click Build > Configuration Manager… > Make sure that the corresponding `Build` option has been checked for your project.
4. Before you run your project, right-click the project that you want to run > select Set as Startup Project, then run it.
5. If you try to open .csproj file of your project(right-click your project > Unload Project > right-click it again > Edit Project File), in `<PropertyGroup> </PropertyGroup>`, add a new line => `<OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>`, then rebuild and rerun your project, will the error disappear?

**Build**

1. Please close VS, navigate to your solution folder, rename the hidden .vs folder, open VS, open your project, click Build > Rebuild Solution > confirm that no errors appear > click Debug > Start Debugging to run your project and check if the error disappears.

**Visual Studio**

1. Repair VS from VS Installer > More > Repair.
2. Reset VS setting by opening Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio and running [devenv /ResetSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022).